# html text link to deliver a string to a python file

Tags: python, html, cgi

how to create a html text link that delivers a KNOWN string to a python file, then redirects you to that python file?

i'm thinking somthing like this
lets say the string i want to deliver is 'lolipop'.
where would it fit

```
<form action="file.py" method="get">
<input ????? />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

With a hidden html input object.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_hidden.asp